# Annotation inheritance for JAX-RS not working

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs, cxfrs

rest-server.xml:

```
<jaxrs:server id="baseApi" address="http://localhost:8080/myfashions/catalog">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <bean class="com.myfashions.api.service.rest.implementation.CatalogServiceImpl"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="customRequestHandler"/>
        <ref bean="customResponseHandler"/>
        <ref bean="restExceptionMapper"/>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Interface:

```
public interface CatalogService {

    @Path("/categories")
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    SelectCategoryBeanList getMyfashionCategories();
}
```

Class:

```
@Service
@Path("/myfashions/catalog")
public class CatalogServiceImpl implements CatalogService {
    @Override
    public SelectCategoryBeanList getMyfashionCategories() {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

When I called `http://localhost:8080/myfashions/catalog/categories`, I got No root resource matching request path `/myfashions/catalog/categories` has been found, Relative Path: `/categories` exception. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're allowed to omit the `@Produces` annotation entirely. It _is_ inheritable.

Comment: I have edited my question. Could you please mention where I am wrong

Comment: Ever get an answer to this? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried moving the class-level `@Path` from `CatalogServiceImpl` to `CatalogService`?

Answer (score 0):

The address is contructed like :

```
http(s)://<host>:<port>/<webapp>/<servlet URL-pattern>/<jaxrs:server address>/<resources>
```

your address setting is incorrect.

Let's say your web context is myApp, and your servlet url-pattern is /rest/*, to accomplish

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/rest/myfashions/catalog/categories
```

you would need:

```
webapp name = myApp
servlet url-pattern = /rest/*
jaxrs:server address = myfashions
@Path on the class = /catalog
@Path on the interface (on the method) = /categories
```

I typically set an address on the jaxrs:server element only when versioning, or when I actually want multiple rest servers for whatever reason.  Most of the time I set the address as "".

Edit: Alternatively, if you want:

```
http://localhost:8080/myfashions/catalog/categories
```

you would need:

```
webapp name = myfashions
servlet url-pattern = /*
jaxrs:server address = ""
@Path on the class = /catalog
@Path on the interface (on the method) = /categories
```

Comment: Also, found the explanation for this on the cxf pages: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html#JAX-RS-HowRequestURIisMatched